# Displaying image to left and text to the right

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to display the image to the left and text to the right of the image, I have a `li` this is defined like:

```
<div class="row color-accent-1">
      <ul style="display: flex; list-style-type: none;">
        <li style="flex-grow:1;">
            <img src="https://w1.pngwing.com/pngs/546/859/png-transparent-food-icon-delivery-icon-sushi-pizza-delivery-scooter-courier-food-delivery-text-thumbnail.png">
            <div class="content">
              <h2 class="title" style="font-size: 13px; letter-spacing: 1.1px;">
                FREE DELIVERY
              </h2>
              <p class="paragraph" style="font-size: 13px; letter-spacing: 1.1px;">
                On all UK orders over £50
              </p>
            </div>
          </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

However, this is displaying like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You just need to make the `<li>` a flex box by adding the style `display: flex`.

```html
<div class="row color-accent-1">
      <ul style="display: flex; list-style-type: none;">
        <li style="display: flex; flex-grow: 1;">
            <img src="https://w1.pngwing.com/pngs/546/859/png-transparent-food-icon-delivery-icon-sushi-pizza-delivery-scooter-courier-food-delivery-text-thumbnail.png">
            <div class="content">
              <h2 class="title" style="font-size: 13px; letter-spacing: 1.1px;">
                FREE DELIVERY
              </h2>
              <p class="paragraph" style="font-size: 13px; letter-spacing: 1.1px;">
                On all UK orders over £50
              </p>
            </div>
          </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

As a side note: You shouldn't have inline styles in your HTML, since you'll repeat yourself quite a lot, which will make your code hard to maintain and obviously much harder to read. Use [CSS classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/CSS_basics#different_types_of_selectors) instead. Also if you give the class names some thought you can add some meaning to the styles.